# Is there any ORM structure that I can use in Ionic + Cordova mobile app for sqlite3 DB?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, pouchdb, ngcordova

I need features like offline storage, remote data sync, encryption, (Object relational mapping) likes of Hibernate in Java and updated database(or pre populated database) in subsequent release of my app.

It will be very helpful if someone can help me for this. I have already implemented Sqlite3 plugin with ionic+cordova and it is working as well.I have also heard about PouchDB integration but I am not aware about the PouchDB.

Comment: Do you really need an ORM for this?

Comment: Actually the app I am building is in Insurance domain which consists of quit a lot number of tables and cardinality relationships between them is one to many and many to many to many most of the time.

Since it is a data centric app I will require many transactions for each form save. Hence It will be good if I can process all these queries through my DAO layer rather than directly writing SQL statement in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Pouch db is a great tool for offline database , it works on the local storage level,
It is a noSql database ,you can save JSON text and you can even save attachments.
It is great for small database and which does not have to many relations